# On [tokens] and [characters]

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging, tag-synonyms

Various questions on main currently have the [tokens](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tokens) and [characters](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characters) tags. Which tag should be used where is not clearly specified, and their meanings have some overlap. What should we do with them?

Answer (score 5):

I propose we make [tokens](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tokens) a synonym of [lexing](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lexing), since [as Rydwolf said](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63593445#63593445) one only makes sense in the context of the other, and create more granular tags for specific token types (like [whitespace](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whitespace)).